# MQ CachingConnectionFactory SessionCache not working

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have some limitation that I can only have 1 partition of kafka topic which I can listen and still need to improve throughput of message processing and send that message MQ in end during that processing

So once I receive message in kafkaListener, I have used Asycn for further processing (that is for storing message in Db and later post to MQ).

Issue I see Session cache is not working , as once I read from kafkalistner it opens up new thread to do further work and once it reaches to JMS send method, after  certain point I end with MQ error "max connections reach channel capacity" I thin MQRC 2537

Not sure what would be issue and I am using com.ibm.mq /mq-jms-spring-boot-starter as dependency

I have set Session cache to 20 and Async to 30 , does this means it will still try to create 10 more JMS connection, if all 30 threads task comes at almost same time

My understanding to SessionCache is that , only that many max session connection will be created only ..and out of 30 ..10 threads need to wait for JMS session to be available

Please assist , we are using Spring boot

Comment: **Snippet from JMS config **
        Public Caching connectionfactory(){
           .setSessionCache(10) //Try to have Session Cache of 10
        }
        
    **JMS template **
        Public JmsTemplate(){
        Jmstemplate used above CachingConnectionFactory
        }

Comment: @KafkaListener( topic with 1 partition owing some reason cant increase partition){
    
    try{
    Call some service class say Aservice and from there we call DB insertion and MQ put (JMS send)
    }
    Catch{}
    
    }

Comment: Aservice.class{
    
    @Async
    public void execute(param)
    {
    //1) Db Insertion
    //2) Some where we call jmsTemplate send (to queue)
    }
    
    }

Comment: All of what you put in the comments should be added to the question in a code block.

Comment: Please as @JoshMc requests add your code to your question! Running out of connections indicates that you are either not closing them, or spewing multiple simultaneous threads. I expect you have have spring allocate a pool for your app to pull from, but you app does need to release them and give them back to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you end up with too many connections being opened. All the pooling is done in the background for you by spring-jms, and it appears that your pool size exceeds the number of connections that the channel is configured for.

You will need to apply a throttle, by reducing the connection pool. There are caching properties that you can set for `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter`. See https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring

eg.

```
ibm.mq.pool.enabled=true
ibm.mq.pool.maxConnections=5
ibm.mq.pool.blockIfFull=true
ibm.mq.pool.blockIfFullTimeout=60
```

You will need to determine sensible values for your envrionment.